# Google Cloud Composer Airflow sqlalchemy OperationalError causing DAG to hang forever

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a bunch of tasks within a Cloud Composer Airflow DAG, one of which is a `KubernetesPodOperator`. This task seems to get stuck in the `scheduled` state forever and so the DAG runs continuously for 15 hours without finishing (it normally takes about an hour). I have to manually mark it failed for it to end.

I've set the DAG timeout to 2 hours but it does not make any difference.

The Cloud Composer logs show the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: 
Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "airflow-sqlproxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local" (10.7.124.107) 
    and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 3306?
```

The error log also gives me a link to this documentation about that error type: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#operationalerror

When the DAG is next triggered on schedule, it works fine without any fix required. This issue happens intermittently, we've not been able to reproduce it.

Does anyone know the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Composer 1 environments (1.16.3 or earlier)  created before August 12, 2021?

Comment: @RaulSaucedo We are using Composer version 1.17.2 and Airflow version 2.1.2. Created on 8th December 2021

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've upvoted it and will mark it resolved when we actual implement this suggestion. Thanks for your help @RaulSaucedo

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the issue is related to **SQLAlchemy** using a session by a thread and creating a callable session that can be used later in the Airflow Code. If there are some minimum delays between the queries and sessions, MySQL might close the connection. The connection timeout is set to approximately 10 minutes.

Solutions:

- Use the **airflow.utils.db.provide_session decorator**. This decorator
  provides a valid session to the Airflow database in the session
  parameter and closes the session at the end of the function.
- Do not use a single long-running function. Instead, move all database
  queries to separate functions, so that there are multiple functions
  with the **airflow.utils.db.provide_session decorator**. In this case,
  sessions are automatically closed after retrieving query results.